# iPhone SDK - What is the fastest way to grap an image from the camera and resize it to screen size?

Tags: iphone, resize, uiimage, performance

Since UIGetScreenImage() is banned again I'm looking for another fast way to get a 320x480 image representation of the current camera picture.

What would be the fastest way to downsize the image from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo and save it as an jpg?

Comment: Wait, do you want screen image or camera image? Because  `UIGetScreenImage()` is different than getting the camera image.

Comment: I'm trying to get the camera image and resize it (as fast as possible) to 320x480 (screen size). I have used UIGetScreenImage() for that because I did not had to resize the image and it was very fast.

Comment: Ok. I can see now what you are getting at...

Answer (score 0):

You can access camera using AVFoundation tools
[as shown here](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/articles/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera)